# Magento - Add a checkbox to "Edit Customer's Address" formular

Tags: magento

I want to add a yes/no checkbox to "Edit Customer's Address" formular and I want that this checkbox to be also in the database, with the other adress data.

How can I proceed to do that??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: make a custom extension, add another attribute to customer object and edit the templates to show checkbox

Comment: which class or method should I rewrite for this purpose ?

Comment: i guess the customer extension and the block that displays the fields